# TouchDragEnter into a UIButton

Tags: touch, uievent, dragenter

Is it possible to TouchDown outside a uibutton and then dragInside another UIButton with the UIEventTouchDragEnter or something like that?

I need help with the code. I tried it with imageView but i would appreciate a solutions with buttons!

Thank you!

Franhu

Answer (score 1):

The `UITouchDownEvent` event must happen inside the button for the button to track the touch.  The `UITouchDragEnter` event means that the touch started inside the button (generating `UITouchDownEvent`), moved outside the button (generating `UITouchDragExitEvent`)' then moved back inside the button (generating `UITouchDragEnterEvent`).